# What is the workspace name for SYSTEM username in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g

I have installed Oracle 11g. I can connect to database with SYSTEM user from command line by "connect SYSTEM/password" but while doing login through browser I am giving 
SYSTEM as username,
password of SYSTEM 
but can't understand what to write in WORKSPACE

When I checked "manage workspaces" I couldn't see SYSTEM schema in the list.

INTERNAL is the default workspace for ADMIN so please tell me what the default workspace for SYSTEM is.

Answer (score 0):

You can find workspace by executing this

> select * from ALL_WORKSPACES

If there is no workspace for SYSTEM user then you might not seen SYSTEM schema in the list

Comment: In Oracle 10g we can access SYSTEM account from command line & browser too but in 11g SYSTEM account is only accessible from command line not from browser, Is there any way to access SYSTEM account from browser in 11g?

Comment: Its better to use [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index-097090.html) to manage database rather than browser. Its quite Safer and Powerful.

Comment: select * from ALL_WORKSPACES; is showing table or view doesn't​ exist.

Comment: what software are you using in the browser? OEM?